# Concentration of Solute And Solvent

Tags: organic-chemistry

Say I create a solution consisting of one liter of motor oil dissolved in three liters of acetone, and I leave the solution uncovered and allow it to evaporate.

As the solution evaporates, will the percentages of the solute and solvent remain the same?

Comment: No---look up *non-ideal solutions*.

Comment: You should read about [azeotropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mixture, originally 4L of 25% motor oil, loses acetone by evaporation until you have 1L of 100% motor oil. The % of motor oil increases from 25% to 100% as the acetone evaporates off.

Comment: It's a dire simplification. Fuel has significant volatility and solution becomes less non-ideal when concentration of acetone decreases.

Comment: I think motor oil (lubricant) is not appreciably volatile (bp ~ 570 F). If the questioner meant diesel fuel (bp ~420 F), even that is quite non-volatile compared to acetone (bp ~ 134 F). Granted, my answer is a simplification, but not so dire, considering the question.

Comment: Thank you; that's what I meant. A highly-volatile solvent such as acetone mixed with motor oil.